# Why do I get 'OTU abundance data must have non-zero dimensions' error when using filterTaxonMatrix on my R phyloseq otu_table object?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am attempting to filter OTUs that are close to 0 in all of my samples using seqtime's function `filterTaxonMatrix`.

I first created a .biom file, converted from HDF5 format to JSON (per phyloseq requirements) and then extracted the OTUs and taxa using `otu_table` and `tax_table` respectively. When I try applying `filterTaxonMatrix` to the new `otu_table` `phyloseq` object I get the error:

> "Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “otu_table” object: OTU abundance data must have non-zero dimensions."

I am unsure what to do, as when I check the OTU table is non-zero in dimensions. I have included my code, but unable to attach my personal .biome file.

otu_table output:

[image: otu_table output example]

```
# Install SpeciEasi package #
library(devtools)
install_github("zdk123/SpiecEasi")
library(SpiecEasi)

# Install phyloseq #
source('http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R')
biocLite('phyloseq')
library(phyloseq)

# Install seqtime #
install_github("hallucigenia-sparsa/seqtime") 
library(seqtime)

# Set path to json OTU table file #
input.path="C:/Users/kenby/OneDrive/Documents/Grad_Project/SchillerPark/Network_Analysis/Network_code/"
output.path="C:/Users/kenby/OneDrive/Documents/Grad_Project/SchillerPark/Network_Analysis/Network_code/"
biom.path=file.path(input.path,"Schiller_otu_json.biom")

# load the biom file with phyloseq #
phyloseqobj=import_biom(biom.path)
# extract the OTU table with OTU abundances # 
otus=otu_table(phyloseqobj)
otus
# and the taxonomy table from the resulting phyloseq object #
taxa=tax_table

# OTU matrix contains many OTUs that are zero in almost all samples we filter these OTUs, but keep their sum #
filterobj=filterTaxonMatrix(otus,minocc=20,keepSum = TRUE, return.filtered.indices = TRUE)
otus.f=filterobj$mat
taxa.f=taxa[setdiff(1:nrow(taxa),filterobj$filtered.indices),]
dummyTaxonomy=c("k__dummy","p__","c__","o__","f__","g__","s__")
taxa.f=rbind(taxa.f,dummyTaxonomy)
rownames(taxa.f)[nrow(taxa.f)]="0"
rownames(otus.f)[nrow(otus.f)]="0"
```

Comment: it has been added @KevinB

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this error using a different methodology. I recommend using SpiecEasi, and viewing the SpiecEasi github documentation. Utilizing a phyloseq object worked best for me.